# Composite Future is not completing

Tags: java, vert.x

I am working with Vert.x and a MainVerticle written in Java. I need to deploy different types of verticles in configurable number of instances. So, that's why I tried to create a List of futures and afterwards I could use a **CompositeFuture.all()** to complete the process.

The problem is that the composite future never calls the handler. For each verticle, the message *[>] Deployed verticle...* appears. But a the end, the message *[>] Verticles deployment complete* never does. The verticles are working, but I need to perform another actions when all the deploymens were ready.

This is the snippet:

```
  private Future<Void> loadVerticles() 
  {
    Promise<Void> promise = Promise.promise();

    List<Future<Void>> verticleDeployments = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Integer i = 0; i < instancesA; i++)
      verticleDeployments.add(deployHelper(ApiVerticleA.class.getName()));

    for (Integer i = 0; i < instancesB; i++)
      verticleDeployments.add(deployHelper(ApiVerticleB.class.getName()));

    for (Integer i = 0; i < instancesC; i++)
      verticleDeployments.add(deployHelper(ApiVerticleC.class.getName()));

    CompositeFuture.all(new ArrayList<>(verticleDeployments)).setHandler( result -> {
      if (result.succeeded()) {
        System.out.println("[>] Verticles deployment complete"); // This message never appears
        promise.complete();
      }
      else
        promise.fail(result.cause());
    });

    return promise.future();
  }


  private Future<Void> deployHelper(String name)
  {
    Promise<Void> promise = Promise.promise();
    vertx.deployVerticle(name, res -> {
       if(res.failed()) {
          System.out.println("[>] Failed to deploy verticle " + name);
          promise.fail(res.cause());
       } else {
          System.out.println("[>] Deployed verticle " + name); // This message is printed for each verticle instance
          promise.complete();
       }
    });
    return promise.future();
 }
```

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your problem. I tried recreating your setup as such: https://gist.github.com/hsl43/f607cb067aa3a9d1ba5a28a4f44bfeb3. The only differences between my code and yours are that I am only spawning instances of one other type of Verticle (`VerticleB`), and I hard-coded the number of instances to create. In the end, the "Verticles deployment complete" message is logged.

Comment: After debug the application, I found a problem with the start method of a single instance. The Promise wasn't being completed. I made the fix and everything works.

Comment: @Herber230 have you ever seen class DeploymentOptions ? you can set number of instances there and not use loops

Comment: Thanks @DidarBurmaganov. I haven't seen that class, and now I am going to change the code since the solution you propose is more appropiate

Answer (score 1):

There are some conditions in the start method for the verticles. In some cases for a verticle instance the promise wasn't being completed.

```
@Override
public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) {

   /*
   * Some async conditions logic
   */ 

    startPromise.complete(); // Some promises never were completed
}
```